# How to export MDF to Excel or CSV using Python asammdf

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, mdf, asammdf

I have one sample sql server DB `mdf` file .I need to convert the file to excel or csv.i searched but not get correct solution.Finally I found one package from python [`asammdf`](https://pypi.org/project/asammdf/)

I don't know how to do this .i am  really new with python and sql server.

My try

```
  from asammdf import MDF, Signal
    import numpy as np

    with MDF(r'sample.mdf') as mdf_file:
        # do something
    export('csv', mdf_file, oned_as)
```

And i got Error

```
File "test.py", line 6
    export('csv', mdf_file, oned_as)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If any one give me correction.Or else please guide me how to convert mdf to excel or csv some other with windows related.basically i m in  Linux platform

Comment: Well, there's no `alphabet[26]` but I guess you already noticed.

Answer (score 0):

asammdf deals with automotive Measurement Data Format (see https://www.asam.net/standards/detail/mdf)

You need to look for another package that implements sql mdf files

Comment: As for your script error: the statements from the with block need to be indented. Python uses indentation to delimit the blocks